# Block all non-squid traffic for PPTP users

Tags: networking, iptables, squid

I have squid running on a transparent proxy (port 3128) and VPN clients connecting + ip forwarding via PPTPD. I want to allow users to connect to port 80 (3128) but block all other TCP traffic.

I am currently using the following:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ppp+ -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i ppp+ -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i ppp+ -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i ppp+ -p tcp -j DROP
```

Although I can see that the HTTP traffic is going through squid, I expect HTTPS (443) to be blocked but I can still load an HTTPS page when connected to the VPN.

Can you point me in the right direction of what is wrong here to block all NON HTTP TCP traffic from VPN clients?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing maybe the filter table is not hit by VPN traffic. After changing it to FORWARD all works as expected

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ppp+ -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o ppp+ -j DROP
```